# Nuxt3 app is not functioning properly in the production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an app that works well in development mode using `"npm run dev"`. However, when I build it with `"npm run build"` and then run it with `"npm run start"`, it breaks. For instance, dynamic styles, which determine whether a button appears disabled based on whether the user has filled in required inputs, do not function as expected in production. Many other things seem to have become static in the production environment too. What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in another thread, sorry to bother you all. It is as simple as adding the `mode: "spa"` line in your `nuxt.config.ts` file.